# Prove or disprove that if y=x, then 0=0?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I got this wrong on my exam. Where did I go wrong?

Disproof: suppose $y=x$. Then $y-x=x-x$ is true. Dividing both sides by $y-x$, $$\frac{y-x}{y-x}=\frac{x-x}{y-x}$$The right hand side simplifies down to $1$, while the left hand side simplifies down to $0$ since $x-x=0$. Thus $$1=0$$ which is a contradiction.

EDIT: Contrapositive. Suppose $0≠0$ (for example $0.0000000001 ≠ 0.00000000000000000002$). Then there exists $k \in R$ such that $0=0+k$.   Subtracting $x$ from both sides, $0-x=0-x+k$. Adding $y$ to both sides, $0-x+y=0-x+y+k$. Subtracting $0$ from both sides, $k-x+y=-x+y+k$. Subtracting $k$ from both sides, $-x+y=-x+y$. Thus $x=y$.

I'm at a loss as to how I should prove it...

Comment: Where's the contradiction in your edit? I'm pretty sure $0=0$ is true.

Comment: Couldn't really find one. I'll try to use the contrapositive approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've divided by $0$.

Needless to say, this will give you garbage results.

Comment: I don't quite see where I've divided by 0. I think y and x are two distinct numbers?

Comment: You've assumed $x=y$.  They're definitely not distinct.  Subtracting $x$ on both sides yields $0=y-x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Maybe I'll try to prove this using contradiction instead of disproof and get back to you.

Comment: I found that if we assume $y≠x$ for proof by contradiction, then $0=0$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looking back, I'm confused on what you're actually trying to show.  The way it reads now, you wish to show that the statement "$x=y$" implies the statement "$0=0$".  In that case, regardless of whether $x$ actually equals $y$ (or not), $0=0$ is still always true.  The implication $P \to 1$ is always true ($1$) regardless of the value $P$.

Comment: I'm trying to show that $x=y$ implies $0=0$. However, my professor told me that $0 \in R$ can have different meanings, that is, $0$ can be $0.000000001$ and $0$ can be $0.0000000000002$. Therefore, in that case, $0≠0$.

Comment: What your professor is saying doesn't make a lick of sense to me, I'll admit.  What is the context?

Comment: He made the point that there are different kinds of 0 $\in R$ - one 0 can be 0.00...01 and another can be 0.00...02. Both numbers are essentially 0, but they are not equal.

Comment: Also, consider the set $0=(0, 0.00000000000000000000000001]$. The professor asked what's the smallest element in such a set? The point is that if you pick a really small element, there will always be a smaller element (just add another 0 decimal place). Thus, no two elements in such a set are equal. I use the same argument here when trying to prove the contrapositive.

Comment: It sounds like either your professor was sloppy or you didn't entirely understand the question he had asked, because outside looking in, those statements simply aren't true.  $0$ is a single, well-defined number.  Saying that for each $x>0$ there is $y$ such that $x>y>0$ is simply the statement that the real-numbers form a densely-ordered set.  But when someone writes $0$, they should mean the (single) number $0$.

Comment: I guess if I assume that division by 0 is not allowed, then your answer makes sense. But we never proved that in class, so I don't think we're allowed to assume that...

Comment: In fact, the "proof" you gave in your original question is essentially a proof, since you end up with a contradiction at the end.  put without the x's and y's, we have $1\cdot 0 = 0\cdot 0 = 0$, so if division by $0$ were possible, we'd find $1=0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

when $y=x$, $y-x=0$ and hence, you can not divide by $(y-x)$ as division by zero is not allowed.

Comment: I agree, but how do I prove this? How do I know that division by zero is not allowed?

Comment: @TomD1 Since when is division by zero allowed?